# Google MX records won't update

Tags: domain-name-system, g-suite, mx-record

I've read through other questions like this but on and off for 3 weeks now I keep trying to update my mx records in my Google apps account but it always stops at 48 hours and says to try again. I'm hosting my domain on IPower and went to the MX records section. According to Google I have to delete the whatever is in there or lower the priority which I just deleted them all. 
Now this is what I have currently:

```
Priority    Host    Points To:  Action
5               *       ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
5               *       ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
10              *       ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
10              *       ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM
1               *       ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM
```

For the life of me I can't get this to work. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Google's article regarding MX records for iPower, it seems like your records are missing the trailing period at the end.

"To modify your MX records with iPower, you'll need to submit a request to the iPower support team. Follow these steps:

Visit https://secure.ipower.com/cgi-bin/addserv/order.cgi.

Click MX Record Additions/Changes.

Fill out the top of the form with your iPower account information.

Under Replace existing MX Record, enter the following:

New MX Hostname or IP:  ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.

Replace MX which has Priority:
(a number from 0 to 100)    0

Under Add an MX Record, enter the following:

MX Hostname or IP:  ALT1.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.

MX Priority:
(a number from 0 to 100)    10

Click Submit.

Congratulations! Your request is pending, and you should be able to use email at your domain shortly. Requests for changing/adding MX records with iPower may take two to four business days to complete."

The original article is here:

http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=54194&topic=1611273&ctx=topic

Let me know if you have any other questions or need some more information!

Comment: You saved my life, weeks it's taken!!!! You were right, I just had to contact them!

Comment: @Naterade Make sure you mark the answer as accepted with the check mark if it's solved your issue!